# How can I make bison return all the syntax errors?

Tags: error-handling, syntax, flexbox, bison

I'm trying to make bison return all the syntax errors that are in a given test file.
But the problem is that the parser stops whenever it encounters a syntax error and report it
Is there any way to make report all the syntax errors directly?

Comment: Could you add a: [mre] ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to continue parsing after a syntax error, you need to add error recovery rules to the grammar.  Understanding how error recovery works really requires understanding the guts of how bison's shift/reduce parser works. The [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) has a reasonable section on [error recovery](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Recovery.html), which is where you should start.

With good error recovery rules, the parser can can continue after a syntax error and (potentially) find more syntax errors.  You do need to be careful about the return value from `yyparse` after error recovery -- if the error recovery is "successful" and is able to continue parsing, and there are no further errors, yyparse will return 0 (success).